# Why is it possible to write to first row of .ods document by python but not to others?

Tags: python, excel, document, ods

I would like to open .ods table file and write new values into first available cell. Only to first three rows.

But this [code](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel-ods3/) just write it there always again. There is not data save. So how to do it?

```py
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data
from pyexcel_ods3 import get_data
from collections import OrderedDict
import ezodf

data = OrderedDict() # from collections import OrderedDict
data.update({"Sheet 1": [[1, 2, 3]]})
data.update({"Sheet 2": [["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]]})
save_data("moje_data.ods", data)
```

Comment: Your code will successfully create a new file with the contents that you tell it to have. Did you want different contents? Did you want to read the data back again?

Comment: Like I said , I would like to write values to first Avalible cells, So when I rewrite 1, 2 and 3 to for example a,b and c, the new values ale written to first row, I need write it to second in this case...

Comment: Do you mean that each time you run your program you want the sheet to have more rows? Is that to be so for each sheet that you mention? (Your code writes to two separate sheets in the file).

Comment: Yes, More rows and save every new three date to new row.

Comment: if you want to add new values to file then you should first read old values from file (as `OrderedDict`, or normal `dict`), and later add new data to this dictionary, and write it.

Comment: BTW: your links shows how to read data from file and convert it to dictionary using `json`. So you should use it.

Comment: BTW: usually files like Excel can't append directly to file. You have to read all data from file to memory (to Python), next you have to add new values to data in memory, and finally you have to write all data from memory to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read the spreadsheet file at the beginning of your code. Then ensure that `"Sheet 1"` exists, then append the rows that you want and save the file:

```py
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data
from pyexcel_ods3 import get_data


def main():
    data = get_data("moje_data.ods")
    if 'Sheet 1' not in data:
        data["Sheet 1"] = []
    data["Sheet 1"].append([1, 2, 3])
    save_data("moje_data.ods", data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Each time you run this code, the file will contain one more row.